# popupParent not known property of 'ag-grid-angular'

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I have a fully functional ag-grid-angular in my app, but as soon as I add [popupParent] it says that it can't be bind because its no known property of ag-grid-angular.

This works:

```
<ag-grid-angular [id]="name" #grid style="width: 100%;" [gridOptions]="gridOptions" (gridReady)="setDatasource()"(cellContextMenu)="onRightClick()" >
```

This doesn't:

```
<ag-grid-angular [id]="name" #grid style="width: 100%;" [gridOptions]="gridOptions" (gridReady)="setDatasource()" [popupParent]="popupParent"(cellContextMenu)="onRightClick()" >
```

In component:

```
private popupParent: HTMLElement;
```

in constructor I just add

```
 this.popupParent = document.querySelector("body");
```

The expected result should be that I set the popup parent to be the document's body element so when I open the menu it will not be clipped inside the grid.

Answer (score 2):

This was due to my version of ag-grid-angular, which is 11 and so the popupParent property indeed does not exist.